# Get error in AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a simple app, and when I tap the `Exit` to show an `AlertDialog`, the app crashes.

**Code:**

```
final ImageView Exit = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
Exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mp.pause();
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                getBaseContext());

        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Do you want to Exit?...");

        // Setting Icon to Dialog
        alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.exit2);

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            // do something when the button is clicked
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0,
                                    int arg1) {
                                finish();
                                // close();
                            }
                        })
                .setNeutralButton("Rate us!",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            // do something when the button is clicked
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0,
                                    int arg1) {
                                {
                                    Uri uri = Uri
                                            .parse("market://details?id="
                                                    + getPackageName());
                                    Intent goToMarket = new Intent(
                                            Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                                    try {
                                        startActivity(goToMarket);
                                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                                getApplicationContext(),
                                                "Couldn´t launch Google Play",
                                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                                .show();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                // if this button is clicked, just close
                                // the dialog box and do nothing
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
    }
});
```

**LogCat:**

```
03-13 01:13:00.084: I/Choreographer(918): Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-13 01:13:12.114: D/AndroidRuntime(918): Shutting down VM
03-13 01:13:12.124: W/dalvikvm(918): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
03-13 01:13:12.145: E/AndroidRuntime(918): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 01:13:12.145: E/AndroidRuntime(918): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
03-13 01:13:12.145: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:563)
03-13 01:13:12.145: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:269)
03-13 01:13:12.145: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
03-13 01:13:12.145: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
03-13 01:13:12.145: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at rain.dreams.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:116)
03-13 01:13:12.145: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
03-13 01:13:12.145: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
03-13 01:13:12.145: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-13 01:13:12.145: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-13 01:13:12.145: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-13 01:13:12.145: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-13 01:13:12.145: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-13 01:13:12.145: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-13 01:13:12.145: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-13 01:13:12.145: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-13 01:13:12.145: E/AndroidRuntime(918):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-13 01:13:14.864: I/Process(918): Sending signal. PID: 918 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably  `getBaseContext()` causing issue so use current Activity context for creating Alert as:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                                        MainActivity.this);
```